Field Service Mobile App Extension - Translation
Is it possibile to translate Field Service Mobile App Extension label? This would be a great feature, mainly in multi-language environments.
In Field Service Mobile Settings, it's only possible to setup a Label and a Name, but we were not able to find them either in Translation Workbench, Or in Field Service translation overrides.
